# Heisenberg microscope for momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurements

In the "Heisenberg microscope", the position of a particle is measured using a photon. The higher the photon energy, the better the precision in measuring the particle location is, but the larger the uncertainty in its momentum will be (according to the uncertainty principle).

This idea is rather intuitive, but what about measuring the particle momentum arbitrarily precisely? How would one do it?
Naively, one could propose to measure the position at two different times, and then calculate the momentum, but this would not work as after the first position measurement the momentum will be strongly affected. So, how would one imagine an Heisenberg microscope for momentum?

Comment: Can you please add a link to a brief description of the "photon is a device that measures position of particles" idea that you refer to? This idea is not generally well understood. Position of microscopic particles is usually measured via some detectory material medium which gets changed by the particle (vapor chamber, film, ...).

Answer (score 0):

> Naively, one could propose to measure the position at two different times, and then calculate the momentum, but this would not work as after the first position measurement the momentum will be strongly affected.

If the particle has high energy, then this method seems fine. Interaction with appropriate medium won't change very high momentum of the particle easily.

If the particle is moving slow enough, then yes, this method will fail.

One way to "measure" low momentum of a particle stream, indirectly, is to invoke its wave properties in some diffraction experiment like scattering off a crystal, or a double-slit experiment, measure wavelength of the resulting  patterns on some particle detector (screen) and then calculate the momentum magnitude via the de Broglie formula:

$$
p = \frac{h}{\lambda}.
$$

This will work only for a stream of many particles, not if we have only one particle (since one particle can't produce an interference pattern).